# Rails form duplicaiton

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, simple-form

I have a form wizard setup with 4 steps that all work on the same model.

When I fill out the first one and click submit (and am redirected to step 2) the form is already filled out and a duplicate, identical form added below. This happens for each step.

How can i render a completely new form after i click submit on step 1 and am taken to 2 (or 3/4)?

step 1

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, url: wizard_path do |f| %>

  <h2 class="signup">Step 3: Friends Birthday</h2>


  <%= f.simple_fields_for :events do |event_f| %>
    <%= event_f.input :name, :placeholder => 'Enter Persons Name' %>

    <%= event_f.input :date, :as => :date_picker, :input_html => { :class => 'special' } %>

    <%= event_f.input :reccuring, :label => false,  :inline_label => 'Remind me of this event every year?' %>

    <h3>Choose up to 3 interests for this person</h3>
      <%= event_f.association :interests, :label => false, :as => :check_boxes %>

      <%= event_f.input :kind, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => "Birthday" } %>

<%end%>

    <%= link_to "skip this step", next_wizard_path %>
    <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
    <%end%>
```

step 2

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, url: wizard_path do |f| %>

<h2 class="signup"> Married? Add your anniverarsy</h2>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :events do |anniversary_f| %>

    <%= anniversary_f.input :name %>
    <%= anniversary_f.input :date, :as => :date_picker, :input_html => { :class => 'special' } %>

    <h3>Choose up to 3 interests for this person</h3>

     <%= anniversary_f.association :interests, :as => :check_boxes, :label => false %></li>

     <%= anniversary_f.input :kind, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => "Anniversary" } %>
     <%end%>


        <%= link_to "skip this step", next_wizard_path %>
        <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
     <%end%>
```

Controllers

events_controller.rb

```
  def new
      @user = current_user
      @event = Event.new 
    end

  def create
      @user = current_user
      @event = Event.new(params[:event])
      @event.user = User.find(current_user.id)
   end
```

users_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create
      @user = User.new(params[:user])
      if @user.save
        redirect_to user_steps_path
      else
        render :new
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you complete one step then intilize new object and bind this second form to new object.Repeat this step for 3rd and 4th form.

Mean every time initilize

```
     @user = User.new
```

Comment: Are you handle all form in one action?

Comment: Or you can add this line on the top of every form                                <% @user = User.new%>